# error when creating an archive of my cocos2d app

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d-iphone (develop-v2) and xcode 5 and have this error when trying to archive my app: (and not when I compile it)

`libs/kazmath/src/neon_matrix_impl.c:64:15`:

```
error: unknown register name 'q0' in asm
         : "memory", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15" //clobber
                     ^
libs/kazmath/src/neon_matrix_impl.c:93:15: error: unknown register name 'q0' in asm
         : "memory", "q0", "q1", "q8", "q9", "q10", "q11" //clobber
                     ^
2 errors generated.
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Show the code you use to create the archive.

Comment: I opened an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1507&can=1&q=franck4321&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Component%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had to replace:

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
```

by:

```
#if defined(_ARM_ARCH_7)
```

in the file `neon_matrix_impl.c`.

Comment: update: maybe it's less clumsy to fix it in mat4.c and simply remove the ifdef and code that triggers the call to NEON_Matrix4Mul. in the kmMat4Multiply function

Comment: This saved me! I was looking for a solution for this for almost a month now!

Comment: You have to change ARM_NEON to ARMARCH_7 in two files , neon_matrix_impl.c and mat4.c .
64-bit should work fine after that.

Answer (score 9):

This is the error in kazmath if you just change in neon_matrix_impl.c only

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:  
  "_NEON_Matrix4Mul", referenced from:  
      _kmMat4Multiply in libcocos2d-library.a(mat4.o)  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

You have to change ARM_NEON to ARMARCH_7 in two files:

1. neon_matrix_impl.c
2. mat4.c

In both files search for the #if and replace it.

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
```

With

```
#if defined(_ARM_ARCH_7)
```

64-bit should work fine after that.

Comment: It would help if you formatted your answer so that the code had the proper line breaks.

Comment: This helped fix my issue in trying to build my old game built with Cocos2d with 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

`#if defined(_ARM_ARCH_7)` compiles with cocos2D v2.1, but does link errors (on iPad Air).

I've upgraded my karmath library with cocos2D v3 kazmath lib (https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/develop-v3/external/kazmath).

It works for me.